# consecutive dates and appointments in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a sql table that holds engineer, appt_date and appt_slot.

```
engineer_id, visit_date, visit_slot

1,           20/10/12,   All Day
1,           21/10/12,   AM
2,           20/10/12,   All Day
2,           21/10/12,   All Day
2,           22/10/12,   All Day
3,           20/10/12,   PM
3,           21/10/12,   All Day
3,           22/10/12,   PM
```

What I'd like to show is

```
Engineer_id, start_visit,      end_visit

1,           20/10/12 All Day, 21/10/12 AM
2,           20/10/12 All Day, 22/10/12 All Day
3,           20/10/12 PM,      21/10/12 All Day
3,           22/10/12 PM,      22/10/12 PM
```

I'm struggling with the sql to show the breaks in the bookings, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: which RDBMS? sql server? or oracle?

Comment: Do you have any sql code so far? If so, post it

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "breaks in the bookings"? Is there more to it than just getting `min(visit_date)` and `max(visit_date)` for each engineer_id?

Comment: I'm using SQL 2008, yes there is more that just getting min and max, if you look at engineer 3, he has no booking AM on 22/10/12 therefore there are 2 entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is find sequences in the data.  Normally, this is sequences of days.  Your case is harder because you have these slots, which are presumably half a day.

The solution works by converting the slots to times.  I am arbitrarily using 6:00 a.m. for the morning and 6 p.m. for the evening.  I do this using a `cross join`, because the new rows are created for the "All Days" appointments.

With this data strcture, you can use a SQL trick to identify the slots that belong together. The idea is to enumerate the slots for each engineer by the datetime.  Then subtract half a day tiems the enumerated value from the datetime.  This is a constant when the values are in order.  A new value appears when there are gaps.

Finally, group by the engineer_id and the group id to get the data you want.

The following query shows this in action.  It leaves the final results as datetimes, rather than converting them back to slots.

```
with t as (
    select 1 as engineer_id, cast('2012-10-20' as date) as visit_date, 'All Day' as visit_slot union all
    select 1 as engineer_id, cast('2012-10-21' as date) as visit_date, 'AM' as visit_slot union all
    select 2 as engineer_id, cast('2012-10-20' as date) as visit_date, 'All Day' as visit_slot union all
    select 2 as engineer_id, cast('2012-10-21' as date) as visit_date, 'All Day' as visit_slot union all
    select 2 as engineer_id, cast('2012-10-22' as date) as visit_date, 'All Day' as visit_slot union all
    select 3 as engineer_id, cast('2012-10-20' as date) as visit_date, 'PM' as visit_slot union all
    select 3 as engineer_id, cast('2012-10-21' as date) as visit_date, 'All Day' as visit_slot union all
    select 3 as engineer_id, cast('2012-10-22' as date) as visit_date, 'PM' as visit_slot
   ),
   tslots as (
    select t2.*
    from (select t.engineer_id,
                 (CAST(visit_date as datetime) +
                      (case when t.visit_slot in ('All Day', const.slot) then const.hr/24.0 end)
                 ) as visit_datetime
          from t cross join
               (select 'AM' as slot, 6 as hr union all select 'PM', 18) const
         ) t2
    where visit_datetime is not null
    group by engineer_id, visit_datetime
   )
select engineer_id, MIN(visit_datetime) as min_datetime, MAX(visit_datetime) as max_datetime
from (select ts.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by engineer_id order by visit_datetime) as seqnum,
             visit_datetime - 0.5*(ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by engineer_id order by visit_datetime)) as groupid
      from tslots ts
     ) ts1
group by engineer_id, groupid
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Thank you, that's fantastic! Can I extend it though, there may be instances of eve and night work, so some engineers may work consecutive nights instead of days.  How do I incorporate that? :)

Comment: Actually, I meant to add this to the answer.  You need to add a calendar table, because some days are probably not work days (weekends, holidays).  You didn't specify this restriction in your original question, but the only way to solve this problem is using a calendar.  To handle different times of days for engineers, I would suggest working out the queries for the different engineers as separate queries.  Then try to combine them into one.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not quite sure what you mean, even though there are bank hols and weekend, these aren't classified as non-working days, they could be assigned jobs.